# Control NAO with a remote control

Tags: c#, controls, infrared, nao-robot

I would like to control a NAO robot with a remote control by using C#.
There is only an example in Python on the Aldebaran website.
Unfortunately, I haven't learnt Python.
Could anyone help me convert this Python example into C#?
The following links may be helpful to you.
https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/naoqi/sensors/alinfrared-tuto.html#alinfrared-tuto
https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/naoqi/sensors/alinfrared-api.html

```
# -*- encoding: UTF-8 -*-

"""
Receive and display remote buttons event:
"""
import naoqi
import time

# create python module
class myModule(naoqi.ALModule):

    def pythondatachanged(self, strVarName, value, strMessage):
        """callback when data change"""
        print "Data changed on", strVarName, ": ", value, " ", strMessage

# call method
try:
    lircProxy = naoqi.ALProxy("ALInfrared")
    lircProxy.initReception(repeatThreshold = 10)
    pythonModule = myModule("pythonModule")
    memProxy = naoqi.ALProxy("ALMemory")
    memProxy.subscribeToEvent("InfraRedRemoteKeyReceived", "pythonModule",
             "pythondatachanged")
except Exception, e:
    print "error"
    print e
    exit(1)
time.sleep(10)
exit(0)
```

Comment: Maybe you should start with this example written in C#: https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/dev/dotnet/index.html#naoqi-dot-net